# BigTable SDK for GAE running on Java7

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a GAE instance which needs to read and write to BigTable. I am using Java7 and moving to Java8 is not an option(unless its unavoidable).

I am not able to find any BigTable Java client SDK for Java7 in the documentation. Which BigTable Java Client SDK should I use which will work with Java7?

**Here is my research**:

I took a look at the docs and the existing options are the HBase Client APIs which require Java8 - https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-appengine-standard . As I mentioned, I would like to avoid moving to Java8 if possible.

Comment: Java 7 has some security restrictions for all grpc based clients, such as Cloud Bigtable.  GAE flex might work with Java 7; you can see an example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/gae-flexible-helloworld

Comment: So there is no SDKs I can use with Java7 and GAE standard? I can take a look into how I can use GAE flex in the mean time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the combination of Java 7 + GAE Standard + Cloud Bigtable is known to have problems and is not supported nor are there plans to add said support.